# Visual Studio: Hack cannot be create

Tags: c#

Всем привет, сегодня решил написать бота для игры, просто используя класс

```
SendKeys
```

Так вот когда приходит время использовать появляется ошибка, типо запрещено создавать читы... скажите как это обойти?

**P.S**

Вопрос, зачем минусовать? Я в последние время заметил, что очень много вопросов начали просто так минусовать...чё за бред?

Comment: отлов читеров на процессе создания ботов =))))

Comment: Так зачем это сделали? Ведь это просто программа которая эмулирует нажатие на кнопки не более...

Comment: Да блин меня вообще за неправильный ответ аж прям переминусовали (-6) совершенно не зачто причём я мог бы вообще неотвечать на вопрос! После сплошных минусов без причины не хочется участвовать в форуме!

Comment: @Rules

- Ну не участвуйте. Вы в ответе с `-6` написали полную шляпу, и вас заслуженно заминусовали.

- Вообще, вряд ли стоит отвечать на вопрос, если досконально не разбираешься в теме, потому что лучше промолчать, чем дезинформировать человека.

Comment: @Angus123

- А по поводу минусов за вопросы - лично на мой взгяд, вам стоит чуть больше времени уделять самостоятельному исследованию проблемы.

- Если по каким-то причинам самостоятельно не получается, то хотя бы потратьте время на то, чтобы **хорошо оформить вопрос.** Все таки этот самый вопрос вы пишете **один раз,** а читают его `50+` раз, так что имеет смысл написать его так, чтобы читающим людям было удобнее.

Answer (score 7):

- Один из самых простых способов написать `bypass` для такого рода защиты - это создать `asm trampoline`.

> *Смысл заключается в том, чтобы вызывать функцию не с помощью `call X`, а с помощью `call X + t`, эмулируя недостающие `t` инструкций самостоятельно.* В случае не самых сложных защит этого бывает вполне достаточно.

- В свое время я обходил защитые хуки на функции `WinAPI` с помощью примерно следующего кода *(синтаксис _declspec(naked) и ассемблерных вставок специфичный для `Visual Studio`)*:

  ```
  DWORD TrampolinedPostMessage =
      (DWORD)GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary("user32.dll"), "PostMessageA") + 5;

  _declspec(naked) BOOL PostMessageSilently(
      HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
  {
      _asm
      {
          mov edi, edi
          push ebp
          mov ebp, esp
          jmp[TrampolinedPostMessage]
      }
  }
  ```
- *Дальше можете использовать функцию с `asm trampoline` для того, чтобы послать нажатие клавиши:*

  ```
  void SendKeySilently(HWND hWnd, CHAR keyCode)
  {
      PostMessageSilently(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, keyCode, 0);
      PostMessageSilently(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, keyCode, 0);
  }
  ```
- **А вообще говоря, бросайте это дело :)**

Comment: Почему бросать? Пока делаешь уроки, программа сама за тебя бьёт мобов :)